# Equality of exponential functions from geometric series

Tags: exponential-function, exponential-sum

I'm currently trying to understand why the first and second line of this equation [image: bla]

are in fact equal. This is taken from "Introduction to the Physics of Waves" by Tim Freegarde from a chapter about diffraction gratings. The notation is somewhat ambiguos (I think), but from the following lines it becomes clear that $\sin \vartheta /2$ is to be read as $\frac{\sin\vartheta}{2}$. But my question remains, what steps are neccessary to go from the first line to the second line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Multiply the numerator and denominator by the factor $-e^{ikd \sin(\vartheta)/2}$.